How to import android packages in .NET MAUI
I need to use this packages
<framework src="org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.14.0" />
<framework src="org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.4.4" />
<framework src="org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-metadata:0.1.0" />

In my android MAUI application, how can i import this in maui?

In .Net MAUI, the packages corresponding to the three frameworks you provided are Xamarin.TensorFlow.Lite, Xamarin.TensorFlow.Lite.Support.Api and Xamarin.TensorFlow.Lite.Metadata.
You can install these packages in your project -> Manage NuGet Packages. Then you will find them in  in .csproj file.

So, you cannot import android packages unless someone has made it for xamarins?

For example i want to import the package: com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper, this is not from google, and doesn't have a xamarin, how can i import this?

For the Android native packages, .Net MAUI supports to use them by binding libraries, which you can refer to Binding Native Libraries For .NET MAUI.
